# is it possible to have an optionmenu inside another optionmenu in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I want some items from an optionmenu have further options to choose. I know about menu and menubutton widgets, but these dont help me. I have to use optionmenu

Comment: why do the menu and menubuttons not help you? That's all that an optionmenu is -- it is literally a menubutton and a menu, and a tiny bit of code. Why do you _have_ to use an optionmenu?

Comment: i have a list of optionmenu(about 40) and with a button a take the values of them. Also i want to be able to see the choice of each one, as the optionmenu does. is it possible with menubutton?

Comment: yes, it's possible with a menubutton. Like I said, and optionmenu _is_ a menubutton with an attached menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An optionmenu is literally just a menubutton and a menu, with a little bit of syntactic sugar.

Here's a simple example showing how you can have submenus on something that looks just like an optionmenu:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar(value="one")
menubutton = tk.Menubutton(root, textvariable=var, indicatoron=True,
                           borderwidth=1, relief="raised", width=20)
main_menu = tk.Menu(menubutton, tearoff=False)
menubutton.configure(menu=main_menu)

for item in (("Numbers", "one", "two", "three"),
             ("Colors", "red", "green", "blue")
):
    menu = tk.Menu(main_menu, tearoff=False)
    main_menu.add_cascade(label=item[0], menu=menu)
    for value in item[1:]:
        menu.add_radiobutton(value=value, label=value, variable=var)

menubutton.pack(side="top", padx=20, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

If you want the user to be able to pick a different value from each sub-menu, you can just create a new `StringVar` for each menu. However, you'll have to write some code to update the label of the button yourself.